# Not separating database values showing all in the same pop up box

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

So, I have a pop up box that shows when I click on the table row. On that box should be the values from that table row, but, instead, it is showing all inserted rows simultaneously on the same pop up box.

[this is what happens when I open the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iogZa.jpg)

[this is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6kE7.jpg)

Here is the html code that opens the pop up box:

```
<tr id="table_row_<?php echo $num; ?>" onclick="hide('table_row_<?php echo 
$num; ?>'), window.location= '#bg'">
<td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 17px;"><?php echo $row['data']; ?> 
</td>
<td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 17px;"><?php echo $row['sala']; ?> 
</td>
<td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 17px;"><?php echo $row['tipo']; ?> 
</td>
</tr>
<script src="scripts/table.js"></script>
<div id="bg"></div>
<div class="box">
<?php
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `ocorrencia` as o INNER JOIN 
`insere_material` as im ON o.id = im.id");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)): ?>
<p class="data"><?php echo $row['data']; ?></p>
<p class="sala"><?php echo $row['sala']; ?></p>
<p class="tipo"><?php echo $row['tipo']; ?></p>
<textarea readonly id="descricao"><?php echo $row['descricao'];?></textarea>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

JS:

```
function hide(tableRow){
var x = document.getElementById(tableRow);
if(x.style.display === "none"){
x.style.display = "block";
}else{
x.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

I am sure that I have to use javascript to separate the values, but I am still learning and don't know how to do it.

this is the box css:

```
#rcorners1 {
border-radius: 20px;
background: #f2f2f2;
margin-top: -200px;
margin-left: -90px;
padding: 50px;
width: 800px;
height: 400px; 
}
```

this is the targets that bring the box down:

```
#bg:target{
display: block;
}

#bg:target~.sala{
top:290px;
transition: all .3s;
transition-delay: .2s;
}

#bg:target~.box{
top:290px;
transition: all .3s;
transition-delay: .2s;
}

#bg:target~#close{
top:20px;
transition: all .3s;
transition-delay: .2s;
}
```

and the values:

```
.data{
z-index: 0;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: -450px; 
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 23px;
}

.sala{
margin-left: 230px;
margin-top: -450px; 
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 23px;
}

.tipo{
margin-left: 380px;
margin-top: -450px; 
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 23px;
}

#descricao{
width: 600px; 
height: 180px;
resize: none;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: -280px; 
position: absolute;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a css issue, can you show the relevant parts

Comment: do you want me to show the css?

Comment: it would help, yeah

Comment: though only the relevant parts, if pos would also help to make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: `position: absolute;` is one part of the the problem - your loop creates multiple `class="data"`, `class="sala"`, `class="tipo"` items, but then the absolute positioning in the CSS for those classes means they are all placed in exactly the same location on the screen, hence why they look like they're piled on top of each other in your screenshot. I highly doubt you actually need absolute positioning here though. You should be able to place the elemets simply within the box div. Maybe use a table or some floating divs, or flexbox, if you need to lay it out horizontally.

Comment: The other problem is that you're creating one single box and using PHP to pre-populate it with all the values from your database. There is no logic anywhere which tells the page which data to display in the box depending on the clicked row. You need some JavaScript to either show/hide the relevant items (perhaps based on some ID, which is currently lacking), or to fetch the data from somewhere (e.g. from the clicked table row, or from an ajax request) and then display it in the box when the table row is selected.

Comment: the problem is that I am still learning and don't know how to do the javascript :(

Comment: Have you tried to research it? And tried anything to attempt it? Which part of it specifically is giving you trouble? I see you have written some JavaScript above, so you have at least some idea how to get a function to run based on the user clicking on an element. So that's the first bit sorted. And it seems you know how to hide an element, so that's the second bit sorted. Next find out how to show an element (hint: it's pretty much the opposite of how you show them, and it's easy to google anyway.). That's the third bit sorted.

Comment: Then you just need to modify the HTML which PHP outputs within the `while` loop so you can identify one row of data in a single element by its row ID. You already did that with your main table `<tr` id="...` code, so if you think for a moment you shouldn't have too much trouble sorting that part out either.

Comment: ok thank you for the help

Comment: I still didn't find out nothing that helped me... like I don't know how can I make the script to show only the row that I am clicking...

Comment: Please show us your attempt to do so. Then we can fix it for you. It's not clear which part of the process is giving you difficulty. As I pointed out, in your existing code above you have actually already implemented almost all the same patterns of code that you need in order to do this task.